# fullpagejs - dont modify height of one single element in the template

Tags: fullpage.js

I'm using [fullpagejs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs).

It's great, but I'd like to be able to keep the size of some of my elements as it is.

Basically, this is the simple layout I've got:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <div class="container fullscreen body" id="fullpage">
    <!-- Section 1 -->
    <div class="fullscreen-background fullpagescroll bg-position-bottom">...
    <!-- Section 2 -->
    <div class="fullscreen-background fullpagescroll bg-position-bottom">...
    <!-- Section 3 -->
    <div class="fullscreen-background fullpagescroll bg-position-bottom">...
    <!-- Section 4 -->
    <div class="fullscreen-background fullpagescroll bg-position-bottom">...
    <!-- Section 5 -->
    <div class="fullscreen-background fullpagescroll bg-position-bottom short">...
  </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Basically, each section is fullscreen with content inside it.

This is the javascript part of fullpage:

```
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    normalScrollElements: '#section5',
    sectionSelector: '.fullpagescroll',
    autoScrolling: true
  });
```

my problem is that in my template, section5 + footer are the fullsize of the page, but now, with the library, it changed so that section 5 is fullscreen and footer not displayed at all (i cannot scroll past section 5)

Is there any way to keep `#section5` height untouched but still be able to scroll?

I tried:

- moving `#section5` outside the parent div where fullpage is initialized to (#fullpage)
- moving the footer inside `#section5`
- using `fixedElements: '#section5'`
- using `normalScrollElements: '#section5'`

But unfortunately, none of this attempt worked for me.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

PS: I know that there's also the WordPress theme (as pretty obvious I'm developing a WordPress theme), but at this stage (it's basically finished) I can't and I don't want to change to the pre-made WordPress template to being able to use this library's functionalities.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs regarding [how to use smaller or bigger sections](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-smaller-or-bigger-sections) and check the [online example](http://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/BKjRYm).

```
<div class="section">Whole viewport</div>
<div class="section fp-auto-height">Auto height</div>
```

And if you prefer to define it by percentage, try the [offset sections extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/offsetSections.html).

Comment: Cool. exactly what I needed. Thanks Alvaro, and great library ;)

Comment: I tried your answer, but unfortunately it's not working 100% how i'd like to.
section5 now is not fullscreen, just like i wanted. Problem is: i can't scroll into the footer. The footer needs to be outside the div i'm setting to use fullpage, and i guess that's the reason why it's not scrolling to that section...am i right? how do i solve it?

Comment: Nothing should be outside of fullPage.js unless its a fixed positioned element. And in that case, you don't need a new section for it.

Comment: Can you have a quick look at this fiddle and tell me how you would achieve this? http://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/JbJRXV?editors=1010 Is moving the footer inside the content my only solution?

Comment: As I said, if you do not plan to use a fixed positioned element, there's no reason to use any element outside fullPage.js wrapper.